# How to change an a tag at a certain browser width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

I've got this block of code that creates a drop-down sign in box:

```
<li id="login-link"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('#login-link').toggleClass('open');">SIGN IN</a>
```

However, this is being appended to a hamburger menu when the mobile width media query is called, which isn't ideal. My questions is - is there a way to refactor this that changes this drop-down sign in box to simply an a tag (`<a href="signin"></a>`) at the mobile width?

Thanks!

Comment: with jquery you can delete it and/or clone() it elsewhere .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would duplicate the `<li id="login-link">...</li>` element and create a class to display/hide them based on a media query. Something like this maybe:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 599px) {
  .mobile-only {
    display: inherit;
  }
  .desktop-only {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .mobile-only {
    display: none;
  }
  .desktop-only {
    display: inherit;
  }
}
```

```html
<li id="login-link mobile-only"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="$('#login-link').toggleClass('open');">SIGN IN (MOBILE)</a>

<li id="login-link desktop-only"><a href="signin">SIGN IN (DESKTOP)</a>
```

I would consider using [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/) for something like this as well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will help. On the same page, a view opens:

```
                                    <div class="media-left pr-1">
                                        <span class="avatar avatar-md"><img class="media-object rounded-circle" src="../../../app-assets/images/portrait/small/avatar-s-7.png" alt="Generic placeholder image"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="media-body w-100">
                                        <h6 class="list-group-item-heading">Wayne Burton</h6>
                                        <p class="list-group-item-text">to me <span>Today</span>
                                            <span class="float-right">
                                                <i class="la la-reply mr-1"></i>
                                                <i class="la la-arrow-right mr-1"></i>
                                                <i class="la la-ellipsis-v"></i>
                                            </span>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>

                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapse21" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingCollapse2" class="card-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="">
                                <div class="card-content">
                                    <div class="email-app-text card-body">
                                        <div class="email-app-message">
                                            <p>Hi John,</p>
                                            <p>Thanks for your feedback ! Here's a new layout for a new Modern Admin theme.</p>
                                            <p>We will start the new application development soon once this will be completed, I will provide you more
                                                details after this Saturday. Hope that will be fine for you.</p>
                                            <p>Hope your like it, or feel free to comment, feedback or rebound !</p>
                                            <p>Cheers~</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```